# Describing relationships in JSON Schema so that Paw can generate payload

Tags: jsonschema, paw-app, faker

JSON Schema Faker can generate a JSON payload automatically from a JSON Schema. I found some documentation about it on https://github.com/luckymarmot/Paw-JSONSchemaFakerDynamicValue#-faker-api-reference

But there is still one thing I can't figure out how to do: some of the fields in my JSON are references to ids of other elements in the same JSON:

```
{
  "trainings":[
    {
    "title": "English Training",
    "topic": "1234"
    }
  ],
  "topics": [
    {
      "id":"1234",
      "title":"Languages" 
    }
  ]
}
```

`training.topic` must be the same as one `topics.id`.

Maybe there is a way to describe that kind of relationship in JSON Schema but I couldn't find any documentation about it, just some doc about how to reference and reuse JSON schema elements. But most likely there must be a way to describe is in Faker syntax.

Comment: Did you finally manage to find a solution?

Comment: this [thread](https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/issues/299) is what you are looking for.